# Is it possible to run hardhat node & hardhat deploy in Github Actions? | Github Action Stuck for hours

Tags: contract-deployment, ethereumjs, hardhat

Currently using the code below for Github Actions to test local deployment. However, my github actions have been stuck for hours on `Test deploy`.

Any ideas on how I can fix it?

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "test"
  test:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
 steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install deps
        run: npm install

      - name: Test deploy
        continue-on-error: false
        run: |
          npx hardhat node # start localnet
          npx hardhat run --network localhost scripts/test-deploy.js # deploy
```

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it with the use of `&`

```
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install deps
        run: npm install
      
      - name: Start local server
        continue-on-error: false
        run: |
          npx hardhat node &
          npx hardhat run --network localhost scripts/test-deploy.js # deploy
```